# Place of output text file

Tags: c++, xcode, file, output

I've got a strange problem which I need help with. I've made a C++ program that gets some data from a .txt file and writes some data to another .txt file. When I compile and run the program by Xcode, it makes the output file in the same directory as the program file - that's exactly what I need. But when I close Xcode and run the program just by double–clicking on it, it creates an output file in my Users directory. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `argv[0]` to retrieve the full path of your program.

Then, either `chdir` to that path, or open the target file with a full path built from the first one.

For example:

```
char path_buffer[512];

strncpy(path_buffer, argv[0], 512); // This might be /home/user/Desktop/binary.exe

chdir(dirname(path_buffer));    // This is now /home/user/Desktop

fp = fopen("myfile.txt", "w");
```

It is safe to "blindly" `chdir` into whatever `dirname` returns, for `dirname` will return "." (the current directory) in case of error.

Or also:

```
char path_buffer[512];
char new_buffer[512];

strncpy(path_buffer, argv[0], 512); // This might be /home/user/Desktop/binary.exe

snprintf(new_buffer, 512, "%s/%s", dirname(path_buffer), "myfile.txt");
fp = fopen(new_buffer, "w");
```

The above will set `new_buffer` to the full pathname of a file called `myfile.txt` in the same directory of the executable. We need two buffers because `dirname` may return a pointer to static storage, and it would not be safe to append "myfile.txt" directly to the returned string pointer trusting it is a modified version of `path_buffer`.

It would be possible to edit `path_buffer`, without resorting to `dirname`. This causes portability problems, for the directory separator isn't necessarily "/"; it and might be "\".

```
char path_buffer[512];
char *p, *q;
strncpy(path_buffer, argv[0], 512);
for (p = q = path_buffer; *p; p++)
    if (('/' == *p) || ('\\' == *p))
        q = p+1;
strncpy(q, "myfile.txt", 512 - (q - path_buffer));
// You may now use path_buffer as file name:
fp = fopen(path_buffer, "w");
```

Comment: I added these lines:
    chdir(argv[0]);
    ofstream out ("Summary.txt");
But it didn't help - the file Summary.txt still appears in the Users folder

Comment: chdir(argv[0]) will always fail because argv[0] is the path to your binary not a path to a directory, you need to strip the filename part first.

Comment: Updated answer to better explain what I intended.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works perfectly! But function strncpy must look like this: strncpy(path_buffer, argv[0], 512), first goes destination, then C string to copy and then maximum characters to be copied. BTW why not use just strcpy?

Comment: Thanks for the notice, I got my function prototypes mixed up. It is best to use "n" functions (sNprintf, strNcpy) because this way you're sure that you're not writing too much in too small a buffer... "It would be bad".

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I fully understood the question - but I think that you just need to supply a full file name (including path) to your output file.

Answer (score 1):

When you open a file based on its filename or by means of a relative path the file is opened or created relative to your current working directory. It seems like when you run from XCode the working directory is set to the directory where the binary is created whereas Finder sets the current working directory to your home directory when starting new processes.

You can either specifiy the path absolutely (begins with a slash) or compute the location of the binary by combining the result of `getcwd()` and the path specified in `argv[0]`. `argv[0]` contains the location of your binary relative to the current working directory so it can be used to compute the location of the binary as an absolute path.